# Polymer2.4 package typescript definition generation

Tags: typescript, polymer, bower-install

As per the [this declarations](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-01-25-polymer-2-4) are automatically generated from the Polymer source.

I have Polymer2.4 installed and when I build the project, error due to the package's missing typescript definition file is thrown. I am unable to proceed. I have confirmed that latest version is installed. The installation of polymer and its dependencies are done through bower.

One such package is iron-fit-behavior, with iron-fit-behavior.d.ts file absent. A very recent update about config for the type declarations is seen. Any lead to either get the missing file included(not manually adding file) or have some config to generate will be appreciated. 
Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got an update from the Polymer team that the type declarations are work in progress and will be made available soon. In the meantime, typings can be ignored by including the configuration in tsconfig file.